# error in buiding with newer sdk

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

with previous versions sdk it worked completely fine . then I updated sdk using sdk manager .

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Failed to find target with hash string 'android-270' in: C:\Android\sdk

**Console**

[image: Console Picture]

Comment: have you download api 27 sdk files using sdk manager?

Comment: It's most likely caused by an error in your build.gradle file, make sure it has correct values for "compileSdkVersion", "minSdkVersion" and "targetSdkVersion"

Comment: yeah . actually I updated to 27 .0.2 today

Comment: yeah egor it worked .one dot (.) missed . thanks for help

Comment: egor . you better post an answer bout it

Comment: Add your `build.gradle` into question

Answer (score 0):

This caused due to a small mistake in `build.gradle` .
set the

> compileSdkVersion to right way .